# Preventing direct URL access to Rails Controller Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a particular Rails controller method that returns some JSON when I do an javascript ajax request in the front-end.

However, I want to prevent users from directly typing in the url, which displays the JSON that the method returns. I also want to still be able to perform my ajax requests. How can I go about doing this simply? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a thought... You could do something custom in your `respond_to` block for html requests.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { ... } # give them a 404 response?
  format.js { render :json => @obj }
end
```

Or maybe your html.erb template with that name could just show some kind of access denied message. Then you'd just have this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render :json => @obj }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your action with

```
    if request.xhr?
       ...
    end
```

Comment: hey, can you explain a bit of your answer ? what does it do actually

Comment: It checks the request header behind the scene

Comment: oh, can i make a particular url in rails accessible to only particular user_id's? (Only these user_id's can view) else prompt some message saying 'no authorized to view this page or somehing'  with this technique

Comment: Use cancan or alike for your feature

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, right now i am using Devise, is that different from cancan ?

Answer (score 2):

The respond_to filter in rails3 controllers is pretty sweet.

```
YourJsonController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def index
    #non-json requests will receive a 406 error
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes.rb`, you can add :via => :post so your URL accepts only POST requests. See "HTTP Verb Constraints" at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html