# Ajax and Json on Ruby on Rails: not sure about action url

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ajax

First i want to apologize for my bad english. 
How do I use "get" in JQuery if the url is actually an action accessible from the browser? This is in my js file:

```
$.get('/user').success(function(data) { availableTags = data;} );
```

And this is my controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
def index
    @email = User.all.collect(&:email)
    render json: @email
end
```

end

My idea is: filejs(ajax)------->controller(action)------>filejs
This works! I can read the email addresses stored in my db but the url "localhost:3000/user" shows the email list and i don't want it!
So how is possible create a specific controller for my ajax request that is not accessible from the browser?
I do not want that someone can get all the emails of my application simply by accessing this "domain.com/user".

Comment: Do you have any type of log in/use valdiation?

Comment: Hi! I'm using Devise.

Comment: have you set up user and admin models for devise?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

**First is json gets rendered for html request**
This can be solved by [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to)

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @email = User.all.collect(&:email)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @email.to_json }
      end
    end
end
```

Your ajax call will be like this

```
$.get('/users.json').success(function(data) { availableTags = data;} );
```

**Your second problem is restricting access to this action**. For this purpose you can use [cancancan abilities](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities).

Comment: Hi! It's not working. I get this in chrome js-console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way not to see the email in "localhost / user", because otherwise it all works.

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved, now i can use the action to get JSON data for Ajax and redirect from user/index.
Similar question: [Preventing direct url access to rails controller methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629806/preventing-direct-url-access-to-rails-controller-methods)

My Controller:

```
 class UserController < ApplicationController
    def index
      if request.xhr?
        # respond to Ajax request
         @email = User.all.collect(&:email)
         respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render :json => @email }
                     end
        else
        # respond to normal request
        redirect_to tasks_path #the root
        end

    end
end
```

My JS:

```
$.get('/user').success(function(data) { availableTags = data;} );
```